# Use short lived token to push docker image to GCP

Tags: json, docker, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a service account and key json file contents in my process. Trying to spawn "docker gcr.io/my-project/my-image" to upload images to container registry.

I tried `docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://[HOSTNAME]` from [Advanced Authentication tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json_key_file), which returns success during login, but still docker push returns error:

```
You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login
```

Ideally, I would like to trigger docker push without configuring gcloud SDK. Also would not want to store key json contents to a file. I'd like to keep it in process memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct command to run for docker clients 18.03 and newer is `gcloud auth configure-docker`.

If you read the fine print for your command `docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://[HOSTNAME]` it mentions `for older Docker clients` e.g. several years old. This is not the correct command to run today.

With the constant improvements, new features, Kubernetes, etc. you do not want to be running old commands or configurations.

[gcloud auth configure-docker](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/configure-docker)

Comment: That’s a great start!! So looks like use of gcloud sdk is unavoidable. Then what would be the best way to auth to fcloud sdk without storing the key json to file?

Comment: For which purpose? You question is about docker. Starting with 18.03 you don't use gcloud commands but instead use docker commands. Google supports two types of credentials for gcloud (User Credentails and Service Account Credentials). For User Credentials use `gcloud auth login`. For Service Account Credentials read this article that I wrote: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-and-authorizing-service-account-credentials-with-the-cli/

Comment: I've got a program that fetches key-json contents and needs to issue docker push command. I could use 'gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <json-file-path>' command to authenticate, but would strongly try to avoid doing so, because that would require storing key file in the file system. Any way to achieve the same without stroing the key-file?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use a service account with `gcloud`? Setup `gcloud` correctly `gcloud auth login`. Then setup docker correctly `gcloud auth configure-docker`.

Comment: I’m not sure you’re reading original question or my responses. I’m trying to perform orchestration, so login using gcloud auth login is not an option

Comment: Are you trying to do this on your deskop or local server OR on a Compute Engine instance?

Comment: Its a random workstation outsude of compute engine. As i mentioned earlier, i got it running by saving ket json file and using auth service-account. But wabted to find a way without saving it to file system

Comment: You only have two choices. User User Credentials or Service Account Credentials for gcloud. I have show you how to use both. Your credentials will be saved to a file - that is the way that gcloud is designed when not running on a Google service.

Comment: As John mentioned, you have to use user credentials or service account credentials, it's the only way to push to GCR. However, you may be able to use [short-lived service account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials) for your use case